# Error al hacer ionic cordova emulate android

Tags: android, ionic, cordova

He creado una aplicación nueva de ionic

```
ionic start test blank
```

Sin modificar nada, intento emularla para Android

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

La salida de consola es

```
Running app-scripts build: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-
ort 35729 --r 35729 --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[12:21:29]  build dev started ...
[12:21:29]  clean started ...
[12:21:29]  clean finished in 4 ms
[12:21:29]  copy started ...
[12:21:29]  transpile started ...
[12:21:31]  transpile finished in 2.53 s
[12:21:32]  preprocess started ...
[12:21:32]  deeplinks started ...
[12:21:32]  deeplinks finished in 9 ms
[12:21:32]  preprocess finished in 10 ms
[12:21:32]  webpack started ...
[12:21:32]  copy finished in 2.72 s
[12:21:40]  webpack finished in 8.93 s
[12:21:40]  sass started ...
[12:21:41]  sass finished in 877 ms
[12:21:41]  postprocess started ...
[12:21:41]  postprocess finished in 11 ms
[12:21:41]  lint started ...
[12:21:41]  build dev finished in 12.40 s
> cordova emulate android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Desarrollo\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate android (exit code 1).
```

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando? Me ocurre lo mismo con otra aplicación (he creado esta vacía para ver si también pasaba sin cambiar nada).
El error es el mismo si lanzo `ionic cordova run android`

- ionic 3.1.2
- cordova 7.0.1
- npm 3.10.9

Comment: Hola hermano hispano hablante, támbien tengo el mismo problema con ionic, utilizo la mismas versiones de cordova y ionic.
Me arroja el error al hacer build y run de la plataforma android.
Si encontrastes el problema, me podrías ayudar a solucionarlo, espero tu pronta respuesta. Thanks de antemano.

Comment: Pues la verdad que lo he dejado un poco de lado ya que en otro ordenador que tengo con Ubuntu no me da el problema. Volveré a intentarlo y postearé la solución si lo consigo.

Comment: Se me ocurre que a lo mejor no has escrito antes en la línea de comandos: `ionic serve`

Comment: `ionic serve` es para crear un servidor local con el que ver la aplicación; el error indicado ocurre cuando el usuario ejecuta `ionic cordova emulate android` con lo que intenta abrir la aplicación en un simulador de android. Son cosas diferentes.

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro: Entendido, gracias!