# No me aparece la ventana del emulador de android en ionic. parte I

Tags: ionic

Empiezo creando mi primera aplicación con la sentencia: `ionic start RedditApp tabs`. Después me muevo hasta el directorio de la nueva aplicación, ingresando en mi consola `cd RedditApp`. Después trato de correr la aplicación escribiendo `ionic serve`. Después ingreso `ionic cordova platform add android`. Después ingreso `ionic cordova build android`, después `ionic cordova emulate android`
y no me aparece la ventana del emulador. [En el video tutorial que estoy siguiendo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QepxfadRc3Y&list=PLYPjmy5IVxT-7FV0uzpG2izFhGoE0Hq2y&index=5) si aparece para ios (también he hecho los pasos anteriores para ios)

Info de mi ionic:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Familia Baldán\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v9.11.1
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 7

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Y esto es un pantallazo de mi consola después de escribir `ionic cordova emulate android`[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Viendo una [pregunta anteriormente publicada que también iba sobre la emulación en ionic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71575/error-al-hacer-ionic-cordova-emulate-android/154558?noredirect=1#comment290043_154558), he aprendido que no tengo por qué escribir primero `ionic serve`, entonces hago todos los pasos anteriormente descritos y me encuentro con esta información:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Alguien sabe qué está pasando?**

Comment: Revisa este post, creo se debe a que no haz configurado la variable de entorno **ANDROID_HOME** https://webxico.blogspot.mx/2015/06/instalacion-y-configuracion-del-android.html

Comment: @Cig: ¿Pero eso no se instala con el Ionic? Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: De hecho es el modulo de android para poder utilizar la componente de **--platform android**

Comment: Una cosa es instalarlo y otra muy diferente el configurarlo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534635/windows-cordova-build-error-failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable

Comment: @Cig: sobre el enlace que me pasas para configurarlo...observo que la estructura de carpetas del android estudio ha cambiado.

Comment: @Cig: Por favor, edita una respuesta para que pueda validarla. Creo que quiero cerrar esta pregunta y hacer una más especifica acerca de como configurar el android studio.

Comment: ntp, cierra esta pregunta y abre otra... Si tu problema no se puede resolver de esta manera intenta con otra. Slds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está relacionado con la configuración de las variables de entorno de las herramientas de android. La info para configurar dichas variables se encuentra  [aqui](https://webxico.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/instalacion-y-configuracion-del-android.html),como ha señalado el usuario Cig. Siguiendo esas instrucciones conseguí solucionar mi problema